# Flutter cloud firestore not updating automatically

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I try to read listen to a stream from Firebase with this code:

```
visibleListsIds.forEach((final String listId) async {
      final Stream<List<WishList>> wishListStream = sharedCollection()
          .document(listId)
          .snapshots()
          .map((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            log.d("updated Document Snapshot: ${documentSnapshot.data}");
            return [
                _getSerializers()
                    .deserializeWith(WishList.serializer, documentSnapshot.data)
              ];
          });
      wishListStreams.add(wishListStream);
    });
```

Where sharedCollection() gives me access to the Firestore instance with the correct collection

I try to write to the collection, with this code

```
DocumentReference postRef = sharedCollection().document(wishList.listId);
    firestore.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
      DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = await tx.get(postRef);
      if (postSnapshot.exists) {
        await tx.update(postRef,
            _getSerializers().serializeWith(WishList.serializer, wishList));
      } else {
        await tx.set(postRef,
            _getSerializers().serializeWith(WishList.serializer, wishList));
      }
    });
```

What happens:

- I can write to Firebase but only one change at a time. When I do the next update, the last one gets reverted.
- I can see the updated data only in the Firebase Console. The App does not show it and it does not show in the log at `log.d("updated Document Snapshot: ${documentSnapshot.data}");`.
- When I modify data in the Firebase Console, I can also not see it change
- **BUT** once I reload the App, all the Data syncs up to the current state of the Firebase Console

Anyone know why I do not get updates with the Stream?
Thanks for your help.

I use the Cloud Firestore Plugin: 
`cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1`

Comment: I would like to test the scenario on my device, can you post it on [Discord](https://discord.gg/pVuUHJ).